# A algorithms from job interview

Tags: c, algorithm

I took a job interview and the following algorithm was asked and I didn’t manage to find out it’s purpose.

```
int func(int a, int b)
{
    int c = b;
    while (c <= a)
        c <<= 1;
    int d = a;
    while (d >= b)
    {
        c >>= 1;
        if (c<= d)
            d -= c;
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. As the interview seems to be over now, did you try it in a debugger and check what happens? Of did you try it on paper with some random numbers as input? You should do this to find out what a function does.

Comment: Seemingly, `a < b returns a`, `a == b returns 0`, `a > b returns ? garbage`.

Comment: If `b == 0` and `a >= 0` it is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function returns the modulo (a%b).

Comment: Only for positive values.

Comment: Implementation defined behaviour shifting signed numbers.